# How do I use the factory pattern if I'm migrating from Angular 1.5.8 to Angular 2?

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, angular-services, angular-factory

If I'm migrating to Angular 2 and I want to use the factory pattern to create a transient dependency (a dependency that doesn't share state between components in which it gets injected), what is the best way to register a service in angular 1.5.8 with plans to migrate to ng2's way of registering services

I know in angular 2, components can reinstantiate services by passing them to the providers array, but that option doesn't exist in angular 1, and it seems like `.factory` is all but deprecated in angular 2 since the docs don't give it much love

An example would be a TabulationService that manages the state of which tab a user is viewing on a dashboard, which would obviously not share state between components. I would want to reinstantiate the service in each component it gets injected into. But I also want to avoid using `.factory` if Angular 2 best practices seem to shy away from using it.

Here is the "hack" I've resorted to, but I don't like it because even though it gets me type hinting and statelessness for my service, I can't use dependency injection in the object that gets created and i have to manage the state of my service when it gets injected and when the component in which it gets injected is destroyed (by manually clearing the service's state):

`tab-manager.service.ts`:

```js
import { TabManager } from './tab-manager.class';

export class TabService {
  manager;

  public initialize(tabs: string[], defaultTab: string) {
    this.manager = new TabManager(tabs, defaultTab);
  }
}
```

`tab-manager.class.ts`:

```js
import { includes } from 'lodash';

const mandatory = (param) => { throw new Error(`${ param } is a required field in Tab Manager!`) };
export class TabManager {
  tab: string;

  constructor(public tabs: string[] = mandatory(`tabs`), public defaultTab: string = mandatory('defaultTab')) { 
    this.checkTab(defaultTab);
    this.tab = defaultTab;
  }

  public switchTab(tab) {
    const self = this;

    self.checkTab(tab);
    self.tab = tab;
  }

  private checkTab(tab: string) {
    const self = this;
    if (!includes(self.tabs, tab)) {
      throw new Error(`{ tab } is not a valid tab. Available tabs are ${ self.tabs.join(',') }`);
    }
  }
}
```

The service then gets initialized by importing the TabManager service from `tab-manager.service.ts` and calling `angular.service('TabService', TabManagerService)

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing to blame Angular 2 documentation on. Angular 1 `factory` service is implemented in Angular 2 DI as [`useFactory` provider](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html#!#usefactory).

It doesn't really matter here if it is `factory` or `service` in this case. Both serve the same purpose and share the same behaviour - they are singletons in Angular 1. Similarly, `useFactory` and `useClass` providers are singletons within the same injector in Angular 2.

To achieve the desired behaviour uniformly in both frameworks a dependency should be instantiated after injection. It doesn't really matter if this is done with factory or constructor function - they should be defined as `value` service in Angular 1 or `useValue` provider in Angular 2.

For Angular 1 it will be:

```
export class TabulationService { ... }
export type TTabulationService = typeof TabulationService;
...

app.value('TabulationService', TabulationService);

app.component('some', {
  controller: class {
    tabulationService: TabulationService;

    static $inject = ['TabulationService'];

    constructor (TabulationService: TTabulationService) {
      this.tabulationService = new TabulationService();
    }
  }
});
```

And for Angular 2:

```
providers: [{ provide: TabulationService, useValue: TabulationService }]
...

@Component(...)
export class SomeComponent {
  tabulationService: TabulationService;

  constructor (@Inject(TabulationService) TabulationService: TTabulationService) {
    this.tabulationService = new TabulationService();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @estus but that doesn't really solve the issue I was discussing.

Angular 1 `value` providers cannot use dependency injection. The use of `.value` is no different and in fact less advantageous than using `.service()` because I at least get DI with `.service()`. The problem is that i have to import a 2nd class and call new on it from a pseudo-constructor function from within the angular `.service()`, which is problematic because the 2nd imported class has no access to DI.

I also wasn't trying to "blame" angular 2 documentation. ng2 is clear about how to make services factory-esque.